# Android - How to edit the size of an image for using as an icon via XML

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, drawable

I have a big image that will be used eventually as an icon for an Action bar. So, I would like to reduce its size before that.

How can I do that via XML?

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/actionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="actionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_gradient_action_bar</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon</item>
</style>
```

icon.xml:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/ford_dtect_logo_on_white"
    android:width="50dp"    -- Doesn't work
    android:height="50dp" > -- Doesn't work
</bitmap>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You will have to create the image the size you want it.

As you can see [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap), there are no `width` or `height` attributes of any kind.

One possibility may be to use `android:gravity="fill"`, but I make no guarantees about this working.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented below, I don't think you can set the size of a drawable via xml. This limits you do having to resize it when you assign it in a View.

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Comment: These are not used for drawable resources.

Comment: @Eric My fault for not being clear. OP would have to set the size constraints of the view containing the bitmap drawable. I do not believe you can set the size of a drawable at all in xml.

Comment: Anyway, I cannot put a view container (such as ImageView), as icon. It must be a drawable (not a layout)